# Can you tell the actual size of an object in a photo by just measuring the image (with some reference objects)?

Tags: optics, image-processing

For example, you took a photo of the surface of a table, which is a rectangle. You also know the length of the table, say 50 inches. In the photo, the surface appears as a trapezoid (whose parallel sides correspond to the table's length). Can you calculate the width of the table by just measuring the trapezoid (angle, length etc)?

You don't know the focal length and the object distance.

Comment: Are you allowed to assume that no camera movements were used?  Even if you can I am reasonably sure the answer is no, you can't.

Comment: @tfb I don't really know what you meant by camera movements (zooming?). So if you can't determine the width of the table with given conditions, what extra information do you need?

Comment: Sorry: 'camera movements' refers to adjusting the geometry of the camera -- and I think the adjustment that might matter here is making the lens & the plane where the image is formed not be parallel.  I am not sure what you need to know to get the information you need, sorry.

Comment: Your title says "with some reference objects". What "reference objects" do you have in mind?

Comment: @sammygerbil For this specific example, it's the length of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is really a math question (3D geometry) rather than physics. The topic is **projective geometry**. Making measurements from photographs is **photogrammetry**.

This question has been asked in [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), for example [Calculate real length of object from perspective image- width of building](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2092449) and [How can I figure out the length of a rectangle when I know the width of it](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2219117). In both cases the OP like you is trying to find the unknown side of a rectangle.

In both cases the answer is No. Lee Mosher's answer to the 2nd question is that with a suitable choice of observer/camera position the images of any two  rectangles can be made congruent. The same is in fact true for all triangles, all parallelograms (but not all quadrilaterals), and also for all ellipses. These classes of planar figure are **projectively equivalent**. See [What classes of polygons are equivalent up to affine transformation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2163435)

Knowing that the object is a rectangle (not a trapezium or parallelogram) is not enough. Some other information is required. MvG's more detailed answer to the 1st question says

> As a general rule, if you know the relative positions of any four non-colinear points in a single object plane then you can compute the transformation matrix and apply its inverse to un-project that plane and read any other dimensions from the image plane.

You can do the same with 3 points on the object line, to find any distances in the object from it image line.

You know the relative positions of 2 points in the object plane (the table). Knowing that the table is rectangular is equivalent to having one other point, so knowing the relative position of a 3rd point on the table (not on the known edge) would enable you to find the length of the unknown side.

Alternatively, knowing the position of the camera relative to plane of the table would enable you to do the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra parameter to consider and that is the "height" of the camera above the object.

[image]

Comment: But those trapezoids have different size of angles, even though the length of lateral sides are different from each other? Can we somehow calculate the width by measuring those angles?

Comment: @Salmonellamayonnaise The point of my photographs was to show that it is unlikely that you can measure the width without further information.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Through your photograph, it's not that obvious to me why it's unlikely to calculate the width.

Comment: @Salmonellamayonnaise When I first started to answer your question I thought that by measuring a couple of lengths on the photograph one could estimate the length but then I decided it would probably not be that easy and that is why I took the photographs. The problem is the foreshortening of the non parallel sides as the camera gets closer to the same "height" as the object which is shown as one moves from left to right. In the photographs the ratio of the lengths of the parallel sides does not change by very much but the lengths of the sloping sides change a great deal.